# Ng-Select does not assign default value even I placed ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is the code I put in HTML.

```
<ng-select 
      [items]="sensorTypes"
      bindLabel="label"                 
      [multiple]="true"
      placeholder="Select"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedAttributes">
</ng-select>
```

The code I place in the TypeScript file are as below

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sensorTypes = [
      { label : "Power", value : "P"},
      { label : "Current", value : "C"},
      { label : "Voltage", value : "V"}
    ];
    this.selectedAttributes = [
      {label : "Current", value : "C"},
      {label : "Voltage", value : "V"}
    ]
  }
```

However, it won't select the `selectedAttributes` by default but the drop-down list works perfectly. It shows the options of Power, Current, and Voltage, just that when I refresh the page it does not select Current and Voltage by default.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ng-select before but simple html select works perfectly for me.

```
<select class="custom-select" name= "anyName" [(ngModel)] = "myVariable"
 style = "width: 100%;">

      <option selected disabled>Select administrative rights: </option>
      <option value="full">
        Full</option>
      <option value="partial">
        Partial</option>
      <option value="minimum">Minimum</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind selected options value using `bindValue` parameter.

```
<ng-select 
      [items]="sensorTypes"
      bindLabel="label"
      bindValue="value"                 
      [multiple]="true"
      placeholder="Select"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedAttributes">
</ng-select>
```

Since binding sensorTypes object's value key, `selectedAttributes` will be array of `strings<value>`.

If you want to select Current and Voltage by default, then initialise `selectedAttributes` as below:

```
this.selectedAttributes = ["C","V"];
```